# Receive null value to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Controller 'ViewUser' getting null value from Tempdata["Identifier']. is there another way to pass the value to the controller?

```js
public IActionResult Details(string Id)
        {
            objInsuredList = (from obj in _db.dbLifeData
            where obj.Identifier.Contains(Id) select obj).ToList();
            
            string strIdentifier = string.Empty;
          
            foreach (var item in objInsuredList)
            {
                strIdentifier = item.Identifier;
 
            }
            TempData ["Identifier"] = strIdentifier;
        }
        
public IActionResult ViewUser(string Identifier)
{
    objInsuredList = (from obj in _db.dbLifeData
                      where obj.Identifier.Contains(Identifier)
                      select obj).ToList();
    return View();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" asp-controller="Exposure" asp-action="ViewUser" asp-route-id="@TempData["Identifier"]">Details</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Because `asp-route` is case sensitive  doesn't match in your case `asp-route-id`

Comment: Could you please share what is the details of `@TempData["Identifier"]` what are you passing in `Identifier` how does it got value?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I've used both id and Id for asp-route. none have worked.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron i'm passing a string value e.g 'js11091969' . a concatenation of firstname, lastname and dateofbirth.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron im getting the value from a list  which i query from a database and loop to it

 objInsuredList = (from obj in _db.dbLifeData
 where obj.Identifier.Contains(Id) select obj).ToList();


foreach (var item in objInsuredList)
{
strIdentifier = item.Identifier;
 }

Comment: Alright got your point, check the answer hope it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Controller 'ViewUser' getting null value from Tempdata["Identifier'].
> is there another way to pass the value to the controller?

Based on your description and comment it seems that you are trying to pass `TempData ["Identifier"] = strIdentifier;` value to your `route value` which is `asp-route-id="@TempData["Identifier"]"` and then you want  to your pass that `Identifier` value to your `controller ViewUser` that is `IActionResult ViewUser(string Identifier)`

**Proper Way To Pass Route Value:**

```
<div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" asp-controller="Exposure" asp-action="ViewUser" asp-route-Identifier="@TempData["Identifier"]">Details</a>
</div>
```

**Note:** Replace the value with `asp-route-Identifier` instead of `asp-route-id`

**Output:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

*Firstly,* I am assigning the value `kiron` to `TempData["Identifier"] = "Kiron";`

then accessing the value to my view as `asp-route-Identifier="@TempData["Identifier"]"` and

*finally,* passing it to `ViewUser Controller`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help bro @md Farid. I really appreciate your effort and time, Helps a lot! :)

Comment: Glad to assist you @Veck